# Can't run commands VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows

I've got this code:

```
 Try
        cmd.Kill()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    TextBox2.Clear()
    If TextBox1.Text.Contains(" ") Then
        psi = New ProcessStartInfo(TextBox1.Text.Split(" ")(0), TextBox1.Text.Split(" ")(1))
    Else
        psi = New ProcessStartInfo("C:/Bukkit Runner/run.bat")
    End If
    Dim systemencoding As System.Text.Encoding
    System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
    With psi
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .StandardOutputEncoding = systemencoding
        .StandardErrorEncoding = systemencoding
    End With
    cmd = New Process With {.StartInfo = psi, .EnableRaisingEvents = True}
    AddHandler cmd.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
    AddHandler cmd.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
    cmd.Start()
    cmd.BeginOutputReadLine()
    cmd.BeginErrorReadLine()
```

And Textbox command

```
        If TextBox1.Text.Contains(" ") Then
        psi = New ProcessStartInfo(TextBox1.Text.Split(" ")(0), TextBox1.Text.Split(" ")(1))
    Else
        psi = New ProcessStartInfo(TextBox1.Text$)
    End If
    Dim systemencoding As System.Text.Encoding
    System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
    With psi
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .StandardOutputEncoding = systemencoding
        .StandardErrorEncoding = systemencoding
    End With
    cmd = New Process With {.StartInfo = psi, .EnableRaisingEvents = True}
    AddHandler cmd.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
    AddHandler cmd.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
    cmd.Start()
    cmd.BeginOutputReadLine()
    cmd.BeginErrorReadLine()
```

But i get this error if i do stop in the console:
http://prntscr.com/9jvf90

The first begin command works OK. http://prntscr.com/9jvfqe

What can i do to run commands in the bat file?

Answer (score 0):

As a Minecrafter, I can clearly see that you are trying to run a Bukkit server.

Maybe this will help?

```
Private Sub MyCode(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles <stuff>
Try
 Try
        cmd.Kill()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    TextBox2.Clear()
Textbox_TextChanged(sender,e)
Catch
End
End Try
End Sub
Private Sub Textbox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Textbox1.textChanged, Textbox2.TextChanged
Try
        If TextBox1.Text.Contains(" ") Then
        psi = New ProcessStartInfo(TextBox1.Text.Split(" ")(0), TextBox1.Text.Split(" ")(1))
    Else
        psi = New ProcessStartInfo(TextBox1.Text$)
    End If
    Dim systemencoding As System.Text.Encoding
    System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
    With psi
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .StandardOutputEncoding = systemencoding
        .StandardErrorEncoding = systemencoding
    End With
    cmd = New Process With {.StartInfo = psi, .EnableRaisingEvents = True}
    AddHandler cmd.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
    AddHandler cmd.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Async_Data_Received
    cmd.Start()
    cmd.BeginOutputReadLine()
    cmd.BeginErrorReadLine()
Catch
End
End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it crashes when running with this code. :( Sorry for my bad English.